# Is it possible to use gmaps4rails without a model/database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

As far as I can tell from the documentation and ReadMe for the [gmaps4rails gem](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki), you need to a model to set as acts_as_gmappable in order to use this wrapper.

In my case I am using simple a form_tag and text_field_tag elements in order to gather the addresses I want to display, and then I want to pass it through the wrapper in order to render the Google Map. I am not storing this gathered data in a database or model.

My questions are:

1. Can this be done with gmaps4rails? If yes can you direct me to an example of a model-less use case or give me any tips on how to do this?
2. If it can't be done with gmaps4rails, is there another gem/wrapper that would work? (I eventually want to show routes and directions)

I understand that I can use the original Google Maps JS V3 API, however I'm trying to keep it in Rails if possible because I'm a total newbie (business guy that decided to learn Rails and make a proto himself in order to attract a tech co-founder) and it seems like it'd be easier to use a wrapper than try to integrate with the API.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with gmaps4rails.

No need for `acts_as_gmappable` which is meant to geocode addresses.

Simply provide the view with something like:

```
@markers_json = [{lat: , lng:, description: }, {lat: , lng:, description: }].to_json
```

`description` will be displayed in infowindow.

Comment: Now my code creates a gmaps div, but no map is displayed. I noticed that you fixed someone elses code in a previous thread with this problem at this same point, however your solution link doesn't work. I am using the exact statement you said would work: <%= gmaps4rails('[{"lng":"30.252442359924316","lat":"59.92999013067258"}]') %> In your other post you said it had something to do with upgrading the gem version. Here are my versions: gmaps4rails (2.0.0.pre, 1.5.6) - Rails 3.2.8 - Ruby 1.9.3p125 - In my gemfile I don't specify a version. I put: gem 'gmaps4rails'

Comment: Also, a separate question.. Without using a model and acts_as_gmappable, how can I geocode an address to pass into the json? Right now I have a @variable that has an address and I want to display the map with that address